# Azure Function temp file

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

When getting content from an endpoint in Azure Functions, I used to be able to save stuff locally and then handle that stuff before passing it to output in Azure Functions.

Now I have this setup:
[image]

1: What happens, when I call my endpoint

2: My function code

3: My call to the function

4: The contents of `C:\Local\Temp` AFTER the function has been called

According to my function code (2) the file `C:\local\Temp\cspcustomer.parquet` should exist, but when trying to read the file I obviously get an error.

Furthermore, when looking at the actual contents of `C:\local\Temp` in Kudu (4), the file is not really there.

My question is, where is my file, so I can continue my work?

Comment: It seems to be something else causing the FileNotFound exception. I poked around in the  Import-Parquet cmdlet. I added a FileInfo check on the file in the BeginProcess section and the file exists.

It seems that the 2 dlls included in the module are not registered at load time.

When Installing PSParquet on Windows or Linux, Import-Parquet runs just fine. Why is it complaining, when running in a function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out this issue will be fixed once the PowerShell workeer is updated: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/733

The PowerShell version in Azure Function is a bit behind. It will be updated to 7.2 as required by the module.

Answer (score 1):

Azure function app has different file system storage locations. Those are

#### **D:\local**

This is local temporary storage, and you cannot share any file from this storage. Temporary storage meaning, this storage goes away as soon as you delete your Azure function from the Virtual Machine. You can store up to 500MB data here.

If your **[Azure function](https://azurelessons.com/create-azure-function-visual-studio-code/)** has to say 3 instances, each one of these instances will actually run on its own **[virtual machine](https://azurelessons.com/create-a-virtual-machine-in-azure/)**, and ultimately, each instance will have its own **D:\local** storage up to **500MB**.

#### **D:\Home**

This storage is shared storage. There are no restrictions, All your **Azure Function** app instances will have access to this storage. In this storage case, If you will delete your Azure function app or moved it to somewhere else then the storage will not go away like in the case of **D:\local**. The storage will remain as it is.

You can use the Home directory instead of Local.

[image]

I can able to see the parquet file which is available in Home Directory

[image]

Refer [here](https://azurelessons.com/how-to-access-azure-functions-wwwroot-folder/)

Comment: Hi Delliganesh, the file is created in the temp folder (on C) and exists, as the code shows. I found, that the file, that cannot be found is the dll file referenced in Import-Parquet. This is not an issue when running the same command on Windows or Linux, only in Azure Functions the error shows up.